# Ecological specialization and relative abundance

Tags: evolution, ecology, natural-selection, population-genetics, population-biology

I am reading [Evolution in Changing Environments by R. Levin](https://www.amazon.ca/Evolution-Changing-Environments-Theoretical-Explorations/dp/0691080623/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1464831742&sr=8-1&keywords=changing%20environment%20levin) but have a hard time.

**Claim**

At page 25, Levin says as a conclusion

> The more efficient a caste at meeting the contingency for which it is specialized, the lower its abundance. This is seen in Figure 2.5b

Here is figure 2.5b <sub>It is actually a reprodcution I did in R but ressemble closely the original</sub>

[image]

**W1** is the fitness in environment 1 and **W2** is the fitness in environment 2. The figures comes with the following legend:

> The optimal population consists of two castes in the proportions of the line segments by the Adaptive Function (dotted line). Thus castes **C1** and **C2** are more or less equally common, but a population of **C1** and the more specialized **C3** will be mostly **C1**.

The terms "Adaptive Function" is not really defined in the book but it basically mean the overall fitness given the fitness components **W1** and **W2**. The terms "castes" and "contingencies" aren't accurately defined either. In his model, the population experiences only these two environments, where $p$ is the probability to be found in one specific environment. As I understand little from this book, it is hard to know what kind of a prior information I could/should give you.

**Question**

Can you help me to understand the above statement and why it makes sense?